# How do I add table header dynamically in c#?

Tags: c#

I have successfully created generating new records into table rows but want to add table header, so how to do that?

```
private void GenerateTable(int rowsCount)
        {
            Table table = new Table();
            table.ID = "Table1";
            Page.Form.Controls.Add(table);
            const int colsCount = 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
                {                    
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;
                    cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            SetPreviousData(rowsCount, colsCount);
            rowsCount++;
            ViewState["RowsCount"] = rowsCount;
        }
```

Comment: put a `new TableRow()` outside of your `for()` loop and put in the header fields there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the suggested solution by @israel-altar, I struggled with adding the header into a <thead> tag and not into a <tbody>.

To achieve this, you have to use the *TableSelection* property of your *TableHeaderRow*:

```
private void GenerateTable(List<string> fieldsList)
{
    Table table = new Table();
    table.ID = "Table1";
    Page.Form.Controls.Add(table);
    
    TableHeaderRow header = new TableHeaderRow(); 
    foreach (string field in fieldsList)
    {
        TableHeaderCell headerTableCell1 = new TableHeaderCell();
        headerTableCell1.Controls.Add(new Literal() {
            Text = field
        });
        header.Cells.Add(headerTableCell1);
    }

    // Set TableSection to TableHeader so that the TableHeaderRow is added within <thead> and not within <tbody>
    header.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    
    table.Rows.Add(header); 
    
    // loop rows ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do it like that:

```
TableHeaderRow header = new TableHeaderRow(); // Creating a header row
table.Rows.Add(header); // Add the header row to table tbl
```

For adding cells in the header row here is an example:

```
 TableHeaderCell headerTableCell1 = new TableHeaderCell();
 header.Cells.Add(headerTableCell1);
```

And this is where is goes in your code:

```
private void GenerateTable(int rowsCount)
        {
            Table table = new Table();
            table.ID = "Table1";
            Page.Form.Controls.Add(table);
            const int colsCount = 3;

             TableHeaderRow header = new TableHeaderRow(); 
             table.Rows.Add(header); 
             //These two lines in iteir own loop
             TableHeaderCell headerTableCell1 = new TableHeaderCell();
             header.Cells.Add(headerTableCell1);
            for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
                {                    
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;
                    cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            SetPreviousData(rowsCount, colsCount);
            rowsCount++;
            ViewState["RowsCount"] = rowsCount;
        }
```

Comment: how to assign header name for columns?

Comment: I mean in my code where to put code for add header for all first column cells?and secode and so on???

Comment: then where is header name assigned?

Comment: when you create each tableHeadearCell, you add it, for example: headerTableCell1.Text

Comment: i am creating three columns so creating three header cells so how to add this three header cells to three columns?

Comment: after you added the cells with  header.Cells.Add(headerTableCell1); you add the header with table.Rows.Add(header);